# sqlite copy data in same table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have table created by query

```
CREATE TABLE [ConsignmentBody] ([ConsignmentBodyID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                [OID] VARCHAR(64),
                                [Body] CLOB);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [ConsignmentBody_OID] ON [ConsignmentBody] ([OID] ASC);
```

I need to cope data in the same table with unique id.

I tried:

```
insert into ConsignmentBody(ConsignmentBodyID, body.[OID],body.[Body])
select (MAX(body.[ConsignmentBodyID])+1), body.[OID], body.[Body] 
from [ConsignmentBody] body
```

> throws near "." syntax error

insert into ConsignmentBody (null , body.[OID], body.[Body])
select body.[ConsignmentBodyID], body.[OID], body.[Body] 
from [ConsignmentBody] body

> throws near "null" syntax error

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

you have autoincrement set on `ConsignmentBodyID`. why do you have to set the value manually? Just insert the records without the primary key and it should automatically be set

```
insert into ConsignmentBody(OID, Body)
select OID, Body 
from ConsignmentBody
```